# Scroll to target inside div with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I want to make scroll to target inside my div with option: overflow:hidden but I doesn't work good. I don't know why my scroll script behave strange. It doesn't scroll to correct target or when I click twice on one button it back to another target. What is wrong with this? Could you help me.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //shows what href contains
    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('.content').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-187 //scroll to top position on href element for example #about
    }, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PGnZN/1/

Comment: Look here http://api.jquery.com/offset/ it gets the coordinates relative to the document so the values are not what you expect them to be

Comment: Oh, it's explain a lot of.. thanks for it. Do you have which function I can use to make it correct or is there a way to use offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.offset()` when you should be using `.position()` http://api.jquery.com/position/ 
`.offset()` gets the coords relative to the document where `.position()` gets the coords from the offset parent. It is important to have position relative on the parent so that the value can be calculated correctly. I did not touch the 187 assuming you wanted it to show it around the middle

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
$('.content').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.position().top-187 //scroll to top position on href element for example #about
}, 1000, 'swing');
```

CSS

```
.inside{
    max-width: 680px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //shows what href contains
    var targethash = this.hash,
    $target = $(targethash);
    $('.content').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top//-187 //scroll to top position on href element for example #about
    }, 1000, 'swing');
});
```